# How can I make a function in one module accessible to another module?

Tags: drupal, module, include

In my custom module, I would like to call `uc_quote_request_quotes()` (for testing purposes). The module has obviously not been loaded  yet because when I try to call it, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function uc_quote_request_quotes()...
```

tf_common.module

```
function tf_common_test()
{
  module_load_include('module', 'uc_quote');
  uc_quote_request_quotes();
}
```

In uc_quotes.pages.inc I have the function defined

```
function uc_quote_request_quotes() {
  //code
}
```

EDIT:
I had to change the `module_load_include` line to be `module_load_include('inc', 'uc_quote', 'uc_quote.pages');`
but that makes me question:

**Is there a way to load the entire module or do I have to load each file individually like this?**

I don't really want to change the info file to make the other module a dependency because this is only needed as a test function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `uc_quote_request_quotes()` isn't available to the `tf_common` module is because the `uc_quote` module is loaded *after* `tf_common` is. Look into [changing the **weight**](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-update-a-modules-weight) of the `tf_common` module to be loaded *after* or change `uc_quote` to be loaded *before*.

Comment: I can't do it this way because uc_quote uses things from tf_common and this is a special circumstance